# How to use short_command_name -args instead of python program_name -args in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'd like to write a simple bash script to write in powershell

```
p args
```

instead of

```
python manage.py args
```

but i have no experience in bash.
Can you help me?

Comment: This is a bit unclear as written. Are you using the Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`) or PowerShell (`powershell.exe` or `pwsh.exe`)?

Comment: I'm using Powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell aliases can't play with parameters, they just alias one name to another. But you can write it as a function:

```bsh
function p {
   & python manage.py $args
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for :D